# what O*(c^n) stand for? is it some how related to log * ? (if so - how?)

Tags: performance, a-star, bounds, approximation

I need to explain this article: 
http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~kowalik/papers/setcover.pdf

and they use this time bound: O*(C^n) \ O*(C^m)
what is this O*?

i looked for it and the only thing that look slimier is the log star but since they use the star inside the function and not as part of the big o - it doesn't look the same

i'm looking for some thing that give a close definition of this bound

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672281/what-is-the-difference-between-the-big-o-and-big-o-star-asterisk-operator

Also the first footnote in the article: "O* (f (n)) notation suppresses polynomial factors".

Comment: Thank you!
the example at the link is great